# Automatically submit input value when switching between input fields > focus lost

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input fields which can be manipulated by keypresses or a jquery keypad plugin.

At this point the only issue left is to keep the input field on focus when switched from one to another. I know the root cause of this issue is

```
$(".keypad-close").click();
```

which is simulating the keypress of the keypad's close (enter) button. this click action is setting focus to the button instead of the new input field:

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
var keypadTarget = null; 
$('#inlineKeypad').hide();
function setKeypads(){
    $('.inlineTarget').focus(function(){
        $('#inlineKeypad').show();
        if (keypadTarget != this.id) {
            $(".keypad-close").click();
            keypadTarget = this.id; 
        }
        $('#inlineKeypad').keypad('option', {target: $('#'+keypadTarget)});        
    });    
}
```

The function `setKeypads()` is initiated from within another function on page load.

HTML:

```
<input step="0.01" value="0.00" id="price-5" class="inlineTarget">
<input type="text" value="0" id="quantity-5" class="inlineTarget">
```

Can anyone of you point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: How about using this $( "inputF" ) .focusout(function() {submit your data...})

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response. The focusout is also actioned on `$(".keypad-close").click();` (as the focus is then switched to the button's focus) so this would be an issue I presume? Somehow I need to reinitiate the focus then the `$(".keypad-close").click();` is actioned. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.inlineTarget').on('blur', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();  

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: {
            value: value
        },
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Tushar. I tried this code and the values are submitted whern switching. But unfortunately the focus of the newly selected input field is still lost. I need to click the input field twice to get the cursor again. Any more suggestions?